# NSString Convert Emojis to HTML Entities

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, character-encoding, html-entities

I have an iOS app and PHP web service that take a user submitted "password" and hash it.

The problem arises when you enter an emoji:

- PHP hashes the salt + &#128525;
- iOS hashes the salt + [heart-for-eyes smiley emoji]

Is there a way to convert the emoji on iOS to the corresponding HTML Entity (like PHP does automatically) so that the resulting hash values are the same?

- `stringWithUTF8String` does not work
- `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` converts it to "\ud83d\ude0d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, perhaps there is a built-in:

```
NSString *emojiString = @"";
NSLog(@"emojiString: %@", emojiString);

NSData *codePointData = [emojiString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
u_int32_t codePoint = *((u_int32_t *)(codePointData.bytes));
NSString *escapedEmoji = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&#%d", codePoint];
NSLog(@"escapedEmoji: %@", escapedEmoji);
NSLog output:
```

> emojiString: 
>   escapedEmoji: &#128525

This based on the fact that the escaped emoji is the decimal number of the code point. The binary code point is the  UTF-32 encoding of the unicode character.
Unfortunately I was not able to find a pre-existing solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! -- To future visitors, I was trying to tackle this problem from the wrong angle. Use PHP to decode instead of iOS to encode.